# Writing multiple blank fields to csv python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a large number of CSVs I am trying to import into a DB table.

My import template asks for a set group of columns.  If my input data only has a few of the desired columns(in my case only 3), I want to put them in their respective columns and leave the unsatisfied ones blank.

For example, the list `List1Column` will go into "List1Column" of my template and so on.  Since this input data does not contain data for my other columns, 'OtherColumn','OtherColumn2' etc., I just want to make them empty. Since I have compiled my input data into lists (each effectively holding a column of data), I am zipping them into the order I want them in my template.

For the empty columns, I am having to feed my template an empty list for each one, `empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty`, in my zip iteration.  Is there a better way to do this? Can I just say  'empty 5 times' instead of `empty,empty,empty,empty,empty,empty`.

My output is the same either way, I just know my method of going about this is poor practice and would like to clean up my code.  I have provided sample csv input with code and output.

#### Input Data

```
$ cat testcsv.csv  

numbers,AthruZ,LthruN  
1,a,l  
2,b,m  
3,z,n
```

#### Code

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

huckFin = open('testcsv.csv','rb')
huckCin = csv.reader(huckFin, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE  )
csvdata = [row for row in huckCin]

List1Column = [row[0] for row in csvdata]
List2Column = [row[1] for row in csvdata]
List3Column = [row[2] for row in csvdata]

empty = ['' for row in csvdata]

with open('file.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvout = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = ',',
    lineterminator = '\n',
    quotechar = '"'
    )

# My template
csvout.writerow(["List1Column",
                 "OtherColumn",
                 "OtherColumn2",
                 "OtherColumn3",
                 "OtherColumn4",
                 "OtherColumn5",
                 "OtherColumn6",
                 "List2Column",
                 "List3Column"])

csvout.writerows(izip(List1Column,
                      empty,
                      empty,
                      empty,  # Is there a way
                      empty,  # to avoid this list
                      empty,  # of empty columns?
                      empty,
                      List2Column,
                      List3Column))
```

#### Output

```
List1Column,OtherColumn,OtherColumn2,OtherColumn3,OtherColumn4,OtherColumn5,OtherColumn6,List2Column,List3Column  
numbers,,,,,,,AthruZ,LthruN  
1,,,,,,,a,l  
2,,,,,,,b,m  
3,,,,,,,z,n
```

Also, I would like to skip the header row. In perl I would use:

```
next if $.==1
```

before looping through the file given the header is the first line.  I assume there is an equivalent in Python.  I am also getting an additional new line in my output ... naturally in perl I would go:

```
chomp($output) if eof
```

I would also assume there is a python equivalent to that as well.  `$output` being my `csvout` object.

If anyone has a better suggestion on how to do this differently or more efficiently overall, let me know.

Comment: Five times an empty list is still an empty list. What output do you expect?

Comment: I would strongly suggest completing a tutorial like [this](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/python) to help you learn basic Python control flow.

Comment: `for _ in range(5): print empty`?

Answer (score 3):

Try `print str(empty) * 5`.

Multiplication as you expect it only works for strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a simple `while`:

```
empty = []
i = 0
while i < 5:
    print empty
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop.

```
for _ in range(5):
    print listname,
```

Note that using the comma in the `print` command means they'll all be on the same line (which it seems like you want).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(*[empty] * 5)
[] [] [] [] []
```

Answer (score 0):

You could stringify empty and then use this print a string x-times option e.g.

```
empty = []
print 5*str(empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into itertools.  For example:

```
import itertools
a=[]
repeat=list(itertools.repeat(a, 10))
print(repeat)
```

Should give you:

```
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```